In Pyspark TempView, comparison of a NULL value in BooleanType column doesn't work as expected
I have a TempView in my PySpark notebook. When I run an SQL query on the view, the WHERE condition below doesn’t produce the expected result:
is_valid != false

For the incoming record, the is_valid column (a BooleanType field) contains a null value. I expected the condition is_valid != false to evaluate to true because null is obviously not equal to false, right?
However, it doesn’t. Instead, it evaluates to false.
I’m not sure what’s wrong with my condition. Any ideas?

This behavior is due to how SQL handles comparisons involving NULL.
Any comparison with NULL evaluates to FALSE. This is because NULL represents an unknown value, and SQL cannot determine if it is equal or not equal to anything else.
Additionally, in SQL, you don't need to explicitly compare a Boolean column to TRUE or FALSE. The column itself acts as the condition.
For example, instead of writing:
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE is_valid != FALSE

You can simplify this to:
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE is_valid

However, if you want to include rows where is_valid is NULL, you need to explicitly handle that with:
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE is_valid OR is_valid IS NULL

This will ensure that both TRUE and NULL values are included in your results.

I'm using SQL syntax here but the same apply to pyspark functions.
df.where(col("is_valid" | col("is_valid").isnull())

# OR

df.where ("is_valid or is_valid is null")



Handling of NULL semantics in Spark is a chapter by itself.
Refer to "Condition Expressions in WHERE, HAVING and JOIN Clauses" section for relevant parts.
If your requirement is that your WHERE clause should evaluate to TRUE when is_valid column is TRUE or NULL then you can do:

WHERE is_valid IS NULL or is_valid (same as WHERE is_valid IS NULL or is_valid = TRUE)
WHERE COALESCE(is_valid, TRUE) ( same as WHERE COALESCE(is_valid, TRUE) = TRUE)



